# strtotime php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, strtotime

All I'm trying to do is make the php file accumulate the end date from the sub date. I don't understand why this strtotime function isn't working. My database stores dates as "Y-m-d".

here's the code:

```
//disguised for security reasons
$db = mysql_connect("*******", "*******","********");
mysql_select_db("*******",$db);

$getad = mysql_query("SELECT id, annual_sub_date FROM members WHERE annual_sub_date!=null", $db);
while ($gad = mysql_fetch_array($getad)) {
$id = $gad['id'];
$asd = $gad['annual_sub_date'];
$aedate_time = strtotime('+1 year', $asd);
$aedate = date("Y-m-d", $aedate_time);
mysql_query("UPDATE members SET annual_end_date='$aedate', annual_active='Y' WHERE id='$id'");
}
```

---------SOLVED IT---------

I went and played XBox Split/Second for a bit and then realised the issue. My mind went back to PHP/MySQL 101. I coded everything right except the "!=null" part.

```
//Wrong Way
$getad = mysql_query("SELECT id, annual_sub_date FROM members WHERE annual_sub_date!=null", $db);

//Correct Way
$getad = mysql_query("SELECT id, annual_sub_date FROM members WHERE annual_sub_date IS NOT NULL", $db);
```

Now everything works :)  That's the issues you can expect coding at 5:01am.

Answer (score 3):

The first argument to `strtotime` is an absolute or relative date as a string, the second argument is an integer timestamp. You're giving it a relative date (string) as the first argument and an absolute date (also string) as the second. You need to convert `$asd` to a timestamp using `strtotime` first.

```
$aedate_time = strtotime('+1 year', strtotime($asd));
```

BTW, you could do the whole date calculation and updating in SQL with a single query, no need to take the long way around through PHP.

Answer (score 0):

It's because **strtotime requires timestamp as second argument** and not string date in Y-m-d.
Just try code snippet below to see what I ment.

```
$gad = array('annual_sub_date' => '2010-11-21');
// wrong
// $asd = $gad['annual_sub_date'];
// good; convert to timestamp
list($year, $month, $day) = explode('-', $gad['annual_sub_date']);
$asd = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year);
$aedate_time = strtotime('+1 year', $asd);
$aedate = date("Y-m-d", $aedate_time);
echo $aedate . "\n";
```